# ScrollView inside a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, scrollview, android-relativelayout

**I need to do a scroll view inside a relative layout.**

When I added the ScrollView this was the result http://postimg.org/image/6abxth299/ where the components are are only taking up half of the screen and when this screen is opened the keyboard comes up by default

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/data_entry_layout">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Post Title"
                android:id="@+id/post_title"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/post_title_input"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/post_title_input"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:textSize="26px"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/post_title_input"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/post_title"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/post_title"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Post Description"
                android:id="@+id/post_description"
                android:layout_below="@+id/post_title_input"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
                android:textSize="26px"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/post_description"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
                android:contextClickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/image_button_icon"
                android:onClick="galleryIntent"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:id="@+id/cancel"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/imageButton1"

               />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Submit"
                android:id="@+id/submit"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cancel"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/imageButton1"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Never use `match_parent` as height to RelativeLayout when inside a ScrollView, change it to `wrap_content`.

Comment: changed it however, components are still taking up half the screen

Comment: what do you want ?

Comment: The height of the imagebutton needs to be responsive (i.e.) it changes depending on what device your are using to take up the whole screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding below to your **AndroidManifest in your this activity** to remove keyboard comes up by default

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"
```

and Use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for scrollview , sugesting to use **LinearLayout** with *vertical orientation* layout for this kind of use.

Answer (score 1):

The height of first dirsct child of scrollview, be it relative or linear layout should be wrap content and not match parent. Also the inner childs should have specific weight or height and not match parent like you have done for imageButton.

Comment: changed the height to 430px and it worked. However, I believe it wouldn't be responsive for other devices right? (i.e. the height wouldn't adjust accordingly)?

Comment: which height did you change to 430px?

Comment: of the imagebutton  <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="430px"

Answer (score 0):

I think ScrollView doesn't work inside Relativelayout. It's better to use LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/data_entry_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Rel12345"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/post_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/post_title_input"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/post_title_input"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:text="Post Title"
            android:textSize="26px" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/post_title_input"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/post_title"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/post_title"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/post_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/post_title_input"
            android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
            android:text="Post Description"
            android:textSize="26px" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/post_description"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
            android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
            android:contextClickable="true"
            android:onClick="galleryIntent"
            />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Rel1234"
            android:layout_below="@id/Rel12345"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:text="Cancel"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/submit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cancel"
                android:text="Submit" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and Try adding below to your AndroidManifes to remove keyboard coming by default

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"
```

Comment: @cgeekmt this one is the tested complete solution of your problem